# Retrieve Dropbox File URL after file uploaded

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I am developing an Android application using the Dropbox Core API. I am uploading files to Dropbox and I want to programmatically retrieve the exact URL of the file after it is being uploaded.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the official Dropbox Android Core SDK, you can get the shareable link for a file using the "share" method:

https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.1-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#share(java.lang.String)

This uses the /shares endpoint on the Core HTTP API:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#shares